# how to get hostname information on TCP via TLS

Tags: node.js

Below is the code from server file. Trying to get the remoteAdress as host name. but it is giving **Remote Address received: :ffff :10.197.0.145** instead of hostname.

```
async function serverImpl(stream) {
    const ctx = {
        id: crypto.createHash("sha256").update(stream.getSession())
            .digest("hex"), // deriving a unique client id from the tls session identifier
        remoteAddress: stream.remoteAddress,
        remotePort: stream.remotePort,
        servername: stream.servername
    }
}
```

We are using TLS handshake for the Security. Expecting hostname from TCP or using TLS mandatorily. Help us on this

Comment: If the IP address starts with `:ffff:` it means the web application is running on a local server . To receive an accurate IP address you must publish your application to a public domain.

Comment: @Tyler2P Thank you for the quick reply. Actually we are focused to get hostname not the IP address.. Any suggestions could you provide ?

Comment: @madhusrimannuru Hostname of what?! Explain in details your application structure

Comment: Hi @Marc,  we are trying to check with what hostname the client is accessing. like domain.com, 1234.domain.com, 4354.domain.com, 545.domain.com, client can access any of them SNI related task it is.. So we would like to get what is the host name he is using to access the resource

Comment: Why is the source/origin of the  "stream" object? Can you draw a litle schematic about your infrstrucuture/application design for me to understand it better?